# Get the max value from each group oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the top value in each group based on `ID_DATE` column from the following record. Group by `ID_TOPIC`

```
CREATE TABLE DA_TBL(
    DATA_ID  VARCHAR2(50),
    REF_DESC VARCHAR2(50),
    DATE_L DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_TOPIC  VARCHAR2(50),
    ID_DATE NUMBER
);

INSERT all 
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('1','sample 1',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'local', 1)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('2','sample 2',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'tradition', 2)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('3','sample 2',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'gospel', 3)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('4','sample 4',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'local', 4)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('5','sample 5',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'gospel', 5)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('6','sample 6',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'tradition', 6)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('7','sample 7',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'gospel', 7)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('8','sample 8',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'local', 8)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('9','sample 9',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'tradition', 9)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('10','sample 10',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'local', 10)
INTO DA_TBL  VALUES  ('11','sample 11',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'gospel', 11)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

What I want is:

```
DATA_ID|REF_DESC |ID_TOPIC |ROWNUMBER|
-------|---------|---------|---------|
9      |sample 9 |tradition|        1|
10     |sample 10|local    |        1|
11     |sample 11|gospel   |        1|
```

What I get is:

```
DATA_ID|REF_DESC|ID_TOPIC |ROWNUMBER|
-------|--------|---------|---------|
9      |sample 9|tradition|        1|
8      |sample 8|local    |        1|
7      |sample 7|gospel   |        1|
```

What I have tried

```
 SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DATA_ID, REF_DESC, ID_TOPIC 
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY DATA_ID DESC) AS rownumber
         FROM  DA_TBL ORDER BY DATA_ID DESC)
 WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query :

```
SELECT 
  t1.DATA_ID,
  t1.REF_DESC,
  t1.ID_TOPIC
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    ID_TOPIC, 
    MAX(ID_DATE) AS maxIdDate
  FROM yourTable 
  GROUP BY ID_TOPIC
) t2 ON t1.ID_TOPIC = t2.ID_TOPIC AND t1.ID_DATE = t2.maxIdDate
```

I think you used the wrong column in your query, so it should also work if you fix it this way :

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATA_ID, 
    REF_DESC, 
    ID_TOPIC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY ID_DATE DESC) AS rownumber
  FROM DA_TBL
) t
WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

Comment: Have you tried? I am get `SQL Error [918] [42000]: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

Comment: My bad sorry, i have edited my query, it should work now

Comment: This still suffers from wrong datatype on column `data_id`

Comment: I agree that data_id is not a number as it should but i am using ID_DATE here which is a number "I want to get the top value in each group based on ID_DATE"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `DATA_ID` column's datatype. It is a string, and strings are sorted differently than numbers. 9 is "larger" than 10.

If you can, modify column's datatype to `NUMBER`.

Or, apply `TO_NUMBER` here:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(DATA_ID) DESC)
                                                  ------------------
                                                  here
```

This might not work if column contains **alpha**numeric values.

```
SQL> l
  1  SELECT *
  2    FROM (SELECT DATA_ID, REF_DESC, ID_TOPIC
  3                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY to_number(DATA_ID) DESC) AS rownumber
  4           FROM  DA_TBL ORDER BY DATA_ID DESC)
  5*  WHERE rownumber = 1
SQL> /

DATA_ID REF_DESC   ID_TOPIC    ROWNUMBER
------- ---------- ---------- ----------
9       sample 9   tradition           1
11      sample 11  gospel              1
10      sample 10  local               1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `varchar` datatype on `DATA_ID`.

For correct ordering (you expect integer ordering, not a text order), you need to cast it:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY CAST(DATA_ID AS NUMBER) DESC)
```

Side note: datatypes in your tables are wrong - if you have an ID, it naturally should be stored as a number (unless you have some special requirements).

From what you posted, you store two ID columns as `varchar`, it should be `number` instead.

Comment: Then change it, if you can - it will really repay you in future. As you can see, this can cause problems...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the top value in each group based on ID_DATE

If so, why are you focusing on `DATA_ID`?

The query you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DATA_ID, REF_DESC, ID_TOPIC ,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TOPIC ORDER BY ID_DATE DESC) AS rownumber
      FROM  DA_TBL
     )
WHERE rownumber = 1
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(DATA_ID) DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f4a4fcfa2218bf429a6400ca7a44cb81) is a db<>fiddle.